# TypeScript error TS2304: Cannot find name 'category'

Tags: typescript, type-hinting

Is it even possible in TypeScript to type-hint a constructor parameter with my custom class type?

I get the above error for this code:

```js
// ProductCategoryDTO.ts
'use strict';

import ProductCategory from './ProductCategory';

export default class ProductCategoryDTO {
    constructor(ProductCategory: category) {
        // do somenthing
    }
}
```

```js
// ProductCategory.ts
'use strict'

export default class ProductCategory {
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/domain/services/ProductCategoryDTO.ts:7:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'category'.

7  constructor(ProductCategory: category) {
```

What is wrong with this code to get the error?

Comment: wrong way around: `constructor(category: ProductCategory)`

Comment: @Marv, gosh! I knew it was something very basic. Coming from the other language the wrong way looks so natural :) Thanks a lot.